# Are address offsets resolved during compile time in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, memory, offset, resolve

```
void *p = malloc(1000);
*((int*)p) = 666;
*((int*)p+sizeof(int)) = 777;
int i;
for (i = 0; i<10; ++i)
    printf("%d ", *((int*)p+sizeof(int)*i));
```

Is the manual offset being resolved at compile time or does it add overhead of performing arithmetic operations during runtime?

Comment: Why don't you look at the assembly produced and judge for yourself? It's not clear what offset you're talking about, and it will possibly depend on your compiler and optimization settings.

Comment: I am talking about the offset from the address of the p pointer.

Comment: There's three of those, one inside a loop. And my comment above applies: check what your compiler produces.

Comment: That is some pretty monstrous code...

Comment: @Mat - I deliberately put 3 different scenarios to make a point. I am not very good at reading assembly, that is why I asked here.

Comment: What compiler for what platform with what optimization settings? I claim too localized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you have a constant instead of `sizeof(int)`, compiler cannot know in advance the address in `p`, so it will have to do the addition. If you have something like `i = sizeof(int)+4` then it should do the optimization compile time and directly set `i` to `8`.

Also, I think when you do:

```
*((int*)p+sizeof(int)) = 777;
```

what you mean is:

```
*((int*)p + 1) = 777; /* or ((int*)p)[1] = 777; */
```

similarly `printf("%d ", *((int*)p+sizeof(int)*i));` should be:

```
printf("%d ", *((int*)p + i));
```

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(int)` is definitely known at compile time and it makes all sense to make efficient use of this information. There's no guarantee, however, that a given compiler will generate something like this:

```
mov dword [ebx+16], 777
```

instead of something like this:

```
mov ecx, 16
mov dword [ebx+ecx], 777
```

or

```
lea ebx, [ebx+16]
mov dword [ebx], 777
```

or even

```
add ebx, 16
mov dword [ebx], 777
```